# layout_marginBottom not working inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I have Android layout listed below, but *layout_marginBottom* is not working - there is no any margin between *myTextView* and *myRecyclerView*.

Any ideas, what may be wrong with my layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:text="*** Descritpion text"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of `ConstraintLayout` are you using?

Comment: @Cheticamp 1.1.0

Comment: I have something very similar where top and bottom margins are not being added. When in a chain or not in chain. i'm using 1.1.2, the ui designer show it fine, but when built and pushed to app.. it's gone, esp when using include layouts

Answer (score 0):

Your `Views` create a chain with a default style of `CHAIN_SPREAD` since there is no `layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` attribute specified for the head of the chain. According to the `ConstraintLayout` documentation:

> **Margins in chains**
>
> If margins are specified on connections, they will
> be taken in account. In the case of spread chains, margins will be
> deducted from the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*** Descritpion text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*** Descritpion text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Actually it is not what I exactly need, because sometimes I hide the TextView and want the margin to disappear as well with the TextView

Comment: @AlexanderLysenko Okey, got your point. Please check updated answer.